# Email alerts from SFDC using office 365

Tags: email-alert

Does any one have an idea about why emails from the partner users  who are using office 365 email address as username and email address for salesforce when they are sending any deal registration approval or new lead creation alert  we are not receiving  the email alerts. Our IT team investigated it and told us that it is due to email impersonation . We used to receive the emails until Jan 2024 now we are facing this issue.

Does any one have a solution  for this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue happen when you are trying to send email using customer or partner’s domain. If you switch to org wide email address, it should fix the issue.

Comment: thank you sorry I didn't get you  can you please explain me where should I change to org wide email address

Comment: So let’s say your partner is Google, now some partner from community takes action and that triggers email using flow. Now if email alert is setup to send using current user email address, org will try to send email using Google domain. This may work in a lot of cases, but for some customers(maybe the one who use office 365, you can’t send email as that domain, as you don’t really own that domain). You mean your company. So it’s best to send customer/partner triggered emails as org wise address. Hope it’s clear now.

Comment: got it thank you